# unused override will be eliminated in dart?

Tags: dart

i have a question related to dart compiler jobs, if i inherited an abstract class there is a lot of functions and attributes but i don't need to use all of them, the compiler will eliminate unused attributes and functions however i have to override them inside my child class?

**for example this unused attribute:**

```
class Chide extends Parent{
  @override
  // TODO: implement extraValue
  Either<ValueFailures, String>? get value => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to provide implementations of the entire interface unless

- your class is abstract, or
- it has a non-trivial implementation of `noSuchMethod`.

It doesn't matter that you know that those methods will never be called, the class claims to implement the interface, so it has to actually do so to be a valid class declaration.

If the code is for testing, so you are pretty certain instances of the class won't reach other people who might think the class is complete, I'd add a `noSuchMethod`:

```dart
class Chide extends Parent{
  @override
  noSuchMethod(i) => super.noSuchMethod(i);
}
```

That will make the compiler believe that you implement all otherwise unspecified interface members using `noSuchMethod`, and it will automatically introduce a `value` getter for you:

```dart
  Either<ValueFailures, String>? get value => noSuchMethod(Invocation.getter(#value));
```